# SED & AWK print entries in a file on one line

Tags: linux, sed, awk

I have bunch of user names  that I get from output of a script command. They are listed  one after the other and I want to print them 5 at a time on one line

my input is

```
eli
mo
joes
hope
tom
bob
smith
etc 
etc 
oinky
```

I want the output to look like this

```
eli, mo, joes, hope, tom
bob, smith, etc, etc, oinky
```

Can you help please ?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk :

```
awk '{if (NR%5 != 0) {printf $1", "} else {printf $1"\n"}}' file
```

The more awkish way, thanks to @JS웃

```
awk 'NR%5{printf "%s, ",$0;next}1' file
```

Or this one from @Jotne, which I find nice :

```
awk '{printf "%s"(NR%5?", ":"\n"),$1}' file
```

- NR : is number of records, basically, the number of line being read
- % is giving you the remainder of the division

So :

Every 5 lines, print the first column of the file ($1, or $0 if you want all columns) and create new line, otherwise write the first column and a comma.

(file is a file with your input)

It gives :

```
eli, mo, joes, hope, tom
bob, smith, etc, etc, oinky
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. I would appreciate if u provided a bit of description on how the command works ?

Comment: +1: Though more awkish way would be `awk 'NR%5{printf "%s, ",$0;next}1' file`

Comment: @theuniverseisflat, I edit my post. Is it clear now ?

Answer (score 2):

```
your_command | paste - - - - - | sed 's/\t/, /g'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat f
eli
mo
joes
hope
tom
bob
smith
etc 
etc 
oinky
```

**Simplest way**

```
$ awk 'ORS = !(NR%5)? RS : OFS' OFS=','  f
eli,mo,joes,hope,tom
bob,smith,etc ,etc ,oinky
```

**OR**

```
$ awk '{$1 = $1} ORS = !(NR%5)? RS : OFS' OFS=', '  f
eli, mo, joes, hope, tom
bob, smith, etc, etc, oinky
```

Comment: Seems clearer to do: `awk 'ORS=NR%5?",":"\n"'`, since OFS isn't used.

Answer (score 1):

```
xargs -n 5 < yourfile | tr ' ' ','
```

Answer (score 1):

lets say your command is **cat fileName.txt** and it gives you  following output :

```
eli
mo
joes
hope
tom
bob
smith
etc 
etc 
oinky
```

so use ***xargs*** command like following

> > **cat fileName.txt | xargs -n 5 | sed -e 's/ /, /g'**
> >
> > eli, mo, joes, hope, tom
> >
> > bob, smith, etc, etc, oinky

to get desired output

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it with `awk`

```
awk '{printf "%s"(NR%5?", ":"\n"),$1}' file
eli, mo, joes, hope, tom
bob, smith, etc, etc, oinky
```

Comment: I like this one. I add it in the chosen answer if you don't mind.

Comment: @jeanrjc no porblem :)